# off-topic question was first search result

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

I was searching for a Python question on Google ("python create file") and the first search result was [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/417757), which is closed as off-topic. The second result, from StackOverflow, had what I was looking for.

Is there a way to discourage search engines from indexing closed questions? I doubt that a closed question would ever be the correct answer to a Google search.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to us to police our own content, it just needed enough close/delete votes; seems my last vote did the trick and the question is now deleted.